# Detectar Click en item agregado dinámicamente a drawer en android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

he creado un navidagtion activity en android studio y bueno este implementa el menú de esta manera:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="Import" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="Gallery" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="Slideshow" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="Tools" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Communicate">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="Share" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_send"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="Send" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

Ahora bien en el activity.tk detecta elclick en los itempreestablecidos de esta manera mediante su ID:

```
override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.nav_camera -> {
                // Handle the camera action
            }
            R.id.nav_gallery -> {

            }
            R.id.nav_slideshow -> {

            }
            R.id.nav_manage -> {

            }
            R.id.nav_share -> {

            }
            R.id.nav_send -> {

            }
        }

        drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        return true
    }
```

ahora yo agrego nuevos elementos al menú de acuerdo a condiciones de la aplicación de esta manera:

```
private fun addMenuItemInNavMenuDrawer() {
        val navView = findViewById<View>(R.id.nav_view) as NavigationView
        val myIntent = Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java)

        val menu = navView.menu
        val submenu = menu.addSubMenu("New Super SubMenu")

        submenu.add("Super Item1").setIcon(R.drawable.icon_cedula)
        submenu.add("Super Item2").setIcon(R.drawable.icon_cedula)
        submenu.add("Super Item3").setIcon(R.drawable.icon_cedula)

        navView.invalidate()
    }
```

lo que no he conseguido hacer es que al hacer clic en estos nuevos items de menú, me dirija a un activity especifico para este, ya que podrían variar como comente a alguna condición, por ejemplo si el usuario es administrador,vendedor o etc.

Comment: Me gustaría añadirte código pero no entiendo muy bien el código que has puesto. Creo que el problema viene de que cuando añades un nuevo elemento al menú te falta crear de nuevo el clickListener de ese menú. Es decir, creas al principio el listener y por eso en los primeros elementos si te funciona, pero cuando añades elementos no refescas ese listener. Pruebalo y me dices.

Comment: El listener ya esta creado por defecto cuando se crea la activity en android studio, el asunto es que una vez se detecta la condición se agregan nuevos elementos al menú, es en estos nuevos elementos que no se como asignarles una id y tampoco el como detectar el clic en ellos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo resolví de esta manera:

**De esta manera agrego los items adicionales al menu indicando, grupo, posicion, y la id asignada**

```
private fun addMenuItemInNavMenuDrawer() {
        val navView = findViewById<View>(R.id.nav_view) as NavigationView

        val menu = navView.menu
        val submenu = menu.addSubMenu("New Super SubMenu")

        submenu.add(0,0, 0,"Configuracion").setIcon(R.drawable.icon_cedula)
        submenu.add(0,1, 0,"Muestra C").setIcon(R.drawable.icon_clave)
        submenu.add(0,2, 0,"Muestra B").setIcon(R.drawable.icon_email)
        submenu.add("")

        navView.invalidate()

    }
```

luego en onNavigationItemSelected los detecto de esta manera

```
when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.nav_camera -> {
                // Handle the camera action
            }
            R.id.nav_gallery -> {

            }
            R.id.nav_slideshow -> {

            }
            R.id.nav_manage -> {

            }
            R.id.nav_share -> {

            }
            R.id.nav_send -> {

            }
            0-> {
                toast("Configuración").show()
            }
            1-> {
                toast("Muestra C").show()
            }
            2-> {
                toast("Muestra B").show()
            }
        }
```